# How to deploy spring boot app to docker

Tags: spring, maven, docker, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy a `Spring-Boot` app to `Docker`. Originally I had the app compile into a `jar`, so I had a main class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation. Locally, everything works fine.

I changed the app so that it creates a `war` file by adding `<packaging>war</packaging>` to my `pom.xml`. I also followed this post: Deploy Spring Boot app to Docker to create the initalizer:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class MyFirstBootApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyFirstBootApp.class);
    }
}
```

Now when I deploy the app to `Docker` it doesn't do anything, I get `404` error when I navigate to the root url. What else am I missing? I checked the server logs and there are no errors or failures, so I'm not sure where else to look.

Used tools are:

- docker 17.06
- jdk 1.8
- Maven 3.5.0
- Sping Boot 1.5.7

Comment: If you want to use WAR packaging, you should consider using a tomcat. Did you configure your tomcat correctly inside your container ?

Comment: Why did you change your packaging from `jar` to `war`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Docker file for your application (put in src->main->docker);

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
ENV SPRING_OUTPUT_ANSI_ENABLED=ALWAYS \
JAVA_OPTS=""

ADD @project.build.finalName@.war /app.war

EXPOSE 8080
CMD echo "The application starting..." && \
java ${JAVA_OPTS} -Djava.security.egd=file:/habil/./urandom -jar /app.war
```

If you need mysql and such things, you need create .yml or .properties files for docker.